# Unable to set location on PowerShell Script which runs from Automata (Ayehu eyeShare tool)

Tags: powershell-3.0, configurationmanager, sccm

### Script i am trying to run from Ayehu eyeShare:

Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1"

Set-Location "LB2:"

### Dir

and out put i am getting is local system C drive files listed not from "LB2:"

LB2: is our site location for SCCM 
nor i am execute any command of configuration manager because the command do not run from LB2 drive , its by default takes C

---

Note: if i run direct from windows PowerShell its works fine but not from Automate tool.

Answer (score 1):

The Account which uses to run the script should have read access to the site

try running it from an account which has access to the site.

Regards,

Kvprasoon